# django 1.5 column doesn't exists

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-1.5

When i added new field to my product model ,it returned error like this->
'Database Error at "/admin/app/product/" column app_product.product_sold_time does not exist LINE 1: ...duct_buy", "app_product"."product_favorite_send"'

Comment: Great, well have fun debugging it, if you need help, you should ask a descriptive question complete with what you have tried and researched so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a field to a model and not to the database, then that new field will have no existing column in the database. The new field will not just "magically" have a column appear in the existing database.

So now your have these options with Django 1.5:

- delete the database and run `./manage.py syncdb` again,
- use [South](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to be able to migrate the database and add columns to existing tables, or
- upgrade Django to 1.7 or above and [use Django's own migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/) to add the new column to the existing table.

Answer (score 1):

You added a new field to you product model, but you have not migrated your DataBase, that's why you get Database Error.

You can upgrade Django using command:

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

than you can use django-commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If you do not want to upgrade Django, install South and follow it`s instructions.
http://test-driven-django-development.readthedocs.org/en/v2.0/08-south.html